# How do I turn a dictionary into a JSON object using simplejson, in Python?

Tags: python, django, json

It's something like this, but this example seems a little complicated.

> > > import simplejson as json
> > >       json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])

My dictionary is:

```
myfruits = {'fruit':4, 'color':11}
```

How can I turn this into a JSON, and then use render_to_response to shoot it to a template?
I'm using Django.

Comment: -1 Assuming that that "complicated" example (taken from the first few lines of the docs) was the only documentation available (which it's not; scroll down), what was stopping you from inferring that the syntax was something like `json.dumps(only_one_arg)` and actually trying out `json.dumps(myfruits)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the easiest way to do it

```
import simplejson as json 
myfruits = {'fruit':4, 'color':11}
json.dumps(myfruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `json.dumps()` (see [doc here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)).

```
import simplejson
simplejson.dumps({'fruit':4, 'color':11})
```